# html iframe in multiple columns

Tags: html, css, iframe, youtube

I am writing a website as a collection of all my stuff (blog posts, YouTube vids etc.) and want to have a page of YouTube embeds. I want to have two columns of embeds, but cant figure out how to. If I edit the css and make the certain bits float to the correct side, it changes nothing. This is what my edited css looks like:

```
    div.leftBodyVideo{
width: 45%;
float: left;
}

div.rightBodyVideo{
width: 45%;
float: right;
}
```

I then changed the html to align the correct tags right, but that didn't work either. it put the iframes that are meant to be right aligned in a weird position:

https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-sur00UJ5A2c/Vb-7rkMrGlI/AAAAAAAAAHk/ZO3CpEcpoQ4/w426-h237/Capture.PNG

Here is the html:

```
    <div id="leftBodyVideo">
    <h5>Pyraminx ao12 16 46</h5>
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/XDN9BXLFGhg" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <br><h5>TheCubicle.US | Yuxin 4x4 + ShengShou pyraminx</h5>
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/vEkiT62B-nE" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <br><h5>Tutorial - sl1pg8r symbol with a cube</h5>
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/2f7xz6ym__0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>

<div id="rightBodyVideo">
    <h5 align="right">Lubing DaYan ZhanChi Cube</h5>
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ydg0APsB7IU" frameborder="0" align="right" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <br><h5 align="right">Cubing - 2x2 ao5 36.9</h5>
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ydg0APsB7IU" frameborder="0" align="right" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <br><h5 align="right">Mindcuber Demo and Explaination</h5>
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/oEIMf1JdyDc" frameborder="0" align="right" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

How can I fix this and get them aligned in 2 columns?

Thanks!

Comment: Try less percentage instead of 45% use 35% for example and so on until adjust.

Answer (score 0):

You are using id's in your HTML but then using class selectors in your CSS so your styles are never applied.

Please try:

```
#leftBodyVideo{
 width: 45%;
 display: inline-block;
}

#rightBodyVideo{
width: 45%;
display: inline-block;
}

<div id="leftBodyVideo">
    <h5>Pyraminx ao12 16 46</h5>
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/XDN9BXLFGhg" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <br><h5>TheCubicle.US | Yuxin 4x4 + ShengShou pyraminx</h5>
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/vEkiT62B-nE" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <br><h5>Tutorial - sl1pg8r symbol with a cube</h5>
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/2f7xz6ym__0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>

<div id="rightBodyVideo">
    <h5>Lubing DaYan ZhanChi Cube</h5>
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ydg0APsB7IU" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <br><h5>Cubing - 2x2 ao5 36.9</h5>
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ydg0APsB7IU" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <br><h5>Mindcuber Demo and Explaination</h5>
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/oEIMf1JdyDc" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

See fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/vhhs76we/).

Comment: And you can add `text-align: right` to the #rightBodyVideo rule to make everything align to the right side. This replaces the `align="right"` in your original code.

Comment: Different arrangement, but still doesn't work :( https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-avPAv_ofXEg/Vb_AtIi-T9I/AAAAAAAAAIU/bQ8CfJRuyPM/w426-h365/Capture.PNG

Comment: Hi @MattyAB, I had made some changes to your HTML as well.  I'll add it to my answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you're trying to do is going to turn out looking sort of like a table layout, so try using `divs` with `display: table`, `display: table-row`, and `display: table-cell`.

Then you can use CSS to further style the cells, giving them padding and text-align if you so desire.

---

**LIVE EXAMPLE** - be sure to click "full page" after you run this snippet so you can see what I mean:

```css
#table {
    display: table;
}

.row {
    display: table-row;
}

.cell {
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="table">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">
         <h5>Pyraminx ao12 16 46</h5>
         <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/XDN9BXLFGhg" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>
      <div class="cell">
         <h5 align="right">Lubing DaYan ZhanChi Cube</h5>
         <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ydg0APsB7IU" frameborder="0" align="right" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">
         <h5>TheCubicle.US | Yuxin 4x4 + ShengShou pyraminx</h5>
         <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/vEkiT62B-nE" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>
      <div class="cell">
         <h5 align="right">Cubing - 2x2 ao5 36.9</h5>
         <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ydg0APsB7IU" frameborder="0" align="right" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">
         <h5>Tutorial - sl1pg8r symbol with a cube</h5>
         <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/2f7xz6ym__0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>
      <div class="cell">
         <h5 align="right">Mindcuber Demo and Explaination</h5>
         <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/oEIMf1JdyDc" frameborder="0" align="right" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That doesnt work for me :( - Don't know why, but it has them still inline on the left column, and actually draws everything twice...

Comment: @MattyAB What browser are you using? My live demo shows up a charm in Chrome.

Comment: @MattyAB Sorry, turns out I accidentally copied the code twice instead of once. Try it now.

Comment: I'm using chrome - the live demo works, but it doesn't work when I put it in the rest of the page.

Comment: @MattyAB Then the problem is with the rest of your page. What does the rest of your page look like?

Comment: Now it's messed up the rest of the page! I copied the code and edited it so it fits, now this has happened! https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-qWbuOsOjUnU/Vb_HBo-_dqI/AAAAAAAAAJE/wuHeWMoHCs8/w346-h192/Capture.PNG

Comment: @MattyAB I'm only using the code you gave me. The code you gave me looked like that. Are you sure you pasted ALL the css rules?

Comment: Oakay, start again. I have reverted it to how it was and the top bar is working. here is what it should look like: https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-uDz53JuRZ1Y/Vb_KFXqqE-I/AAAAAAAAAJ0/xUxgSnJvOtY/w346-h192/Capture.PNG Here is the html: http://pastebin.com/8Qgu5Lbh And here is the css: http://pastebin.com/tQk1dYTk

Comment: Okay, now that works but the index page has stopped fetching the css. here is the index page. I have looked but can't find any immideate problem... http://pastebin.com/Z9dScKCq

Comment: @MattyAB Maybe it has to do with needing an extra space between the `rel` and `href` attributes in your link tag: `<link rel="stylesheet"href="index.css" type="text/css">`

Comment: @MattyAB Also you have a stray `</style>` tag in your document head.

Comment: Dow! That was the problem - thanks for all your help! Also check out my blog: http://thegeekcircle.blogspot.co.uk   (free advertising!)

Comment: @MattyAB Ergh! Well I'm glad I could help! I guess my "accept" on this answer from you will be well-deserved! Also thanks for sharing your blog! Just be aware that comment might eventually be flagged for advertising. And if you want to check out any of my stuff, click on my username and follow through to Portfolio/Resume!